# Node.js updating column from array using loops

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an amount array that is created from `req.body.amount`. If I want to update the 'amount' column of my table using the elements from the array, can I do it using a loop like this:

```
amount.forEach(function (value) {
    let update = [value, req.body.name];
    let updatequery = "UPDATE food_item SET amount = ? WHERE name IN (?)";
    db.query(updatequery, update, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Do I also need another loop for the `req.body.name` array?

Comment: You should consider looking at promises and not use `.forEach`. this is a disaster waiting to happen. I [wrote this](https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/), if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

yea u have to create a nested loop if you have an array like this: arr[4][4]

it will give a table like this:

[image: A 3d Array]

you can update columb as follows:

```
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
   for(let j = 0; j < n; j++){
      arr[i][j] = value;
   }
}
```